window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
I'm working on the front end through Django WebFramework and PyCham, but infinite scrolls are not properly applied
It is a page that fetches and displays public data APIs.
Even if the scroll is stuck to the floor, more content does not come out.
my html templates
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<section>
    <div class="mainpage_content_container">
        <div class="section_wrap">
            <div class="slick_container">
                <div><img src="{% static 'img/gucciSeoul.jpeg' %}" alt=""></div>
                <div><img src="{% static 'img/korean_mood1.jpeg' %}" alt=""></div>
                <div><img src="{% static 'img/white_cow.jpeg' %}" alt=""></div>
                <div><img src="{% static 'img/colorful.jpeg' %}" alt=""></div>
                <div><img src="{% static 'img/6.25.jpeg' %}" alt=""></div>
                <div><img src="{% static 'img/seoulcity.jpeg' %}" alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content_container">
            <div class="content_wrap">
                <ul>
                    {% for image_info in image_info_list %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="img_wrap">
                            <img src="{{ image_info.file_url }}" alt="{{ image_info.art_name }}" style="max-width: 300px; min-height: 350px">
                            <div class="img_info">
                                <p><strong>작품명 :</strong>{{ image_info.art_name }}</p>
                                <p><strong>일련번호 :</strong>{{ image_info.artCd }}</p>
                                <p><strong>작품가격 :</strong>{{ image_info.price }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                    {% if art_list %}
                        <h2>검색 결과</h2>
                            <ul>
                                {% for art in art_list %}
                                    <li>
                                        <p>작품 번호: {{ image_info.artCd }}</p>
                                        <p>작품명: {{ image_info.art_name }}</p>
                                        <p>이미지:
                                            {% if art.image_url %}
                                                <img src="{{ art.image_url }}" alt="작품 이미지">
                                            {% else %}
                                                이미지 없음
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </p>
                                    </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                    {% else %}
<!--                        <p>검색된 작품이 없습니다.</p>-->
                    {% endif %}
            </div>

            <!-- infinite scroll content -->
            <div class="content_wrap">
                <ul>
                    {% for image_info in image_info_list %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="img_wrap">
                            <img src="{{ image_info.file_url }}" alt="{{ image_info.art_name }}" style="max-width: 300px; min-height: 350px">
                            <div class="img_info">
                                <p><strong>작품명 :</strong>{{ image_info.art_name }}</p>
                                <p><strong>일련번호 :</strong>{{ image_info.artCd }}</p>
                                <p><strong>작품가격 :</strong>{{ image_info.price }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                    {% if art_list %}
                        <h2>검색 결과</h2>
                            <ul>
                                {% for art in art_list %}
                                    <li>
                                        <p>작품 번호: {{ image_info.artCd }}</p>
                                        <p>작품명: {{ image_info.art_name }}</p>
                                        <p>이미지:
                                            {% if art.image_url %}
                                                <img src="{{ art.image_url }}" alt="작품 이미지">
                                            {% else %}
                                                이미지 없음
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </p>
                                    </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                    {% else %}
<!--                        <p>검색된 작품이 없습니다.</p>-->
                    {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</section>
{% endblock %}

my css
.content_container {
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

.content_container:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #ff000020;
}

my javascripts
var count = 2;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        var toAdd = document.createElement("div");
        toAdd.classList.add("content_wrap")
        toAdd.textContent = `${++count}번째 블록`;
        document.querySelector('.content_container').appendChild(toAdd)
    }
});

var count = 2;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        var toAdd = document.createElement("div");
        toAdd.classList.add("content_wrap")
        toAdd.textContent = `${++count}번째 블록`;
        document.querySelector('.content_container').appendChild(toAdd)
    }
});

in consol log check it count
max 3 return

Why do you have var count = 2; twice? In fact why are there two identical scripts? It's not clear what's going on with your code.

To make sure the page count is going well

you are missing the actual call to the API and then put the data inside toAdd div

Are you saying that I need to get API data and check it?
sorry My English is suck
